# Running command lerna-changelog throws error "Could not infer "repo" from the "package.json" file." with VSTS repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, azure-devops, lerna

I have Azure DevOps (Formerly known as VSTS) repository https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/DefaultCollection/project_name/_git/project_name and configured with lerna. Publish/versioning works fine with Lerna.

We are using https://github.com/lerna/lerna-changelog

However, while running the command lerna-changelog throws error "Could not infer "repo" from the "package.json" file." with VSTS repo

After checking the Lerna-Changelog code, it looks like its trying to match the repo pattern and fails

lerna-changelog/src/configuration.ts

[image]

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Running command lerna-changelog throws error “Could not infer ”repo“ from the ”package.json“ file.” with VSTS repo

I am afraid you could not use the Lerna-Changelog code in the Azure DevOps repo at this moment.

AFAIK, **the Lerna-Changelog only supports projects hosted on GitHub at this moment.**

As workaround, you could run the build pipeline with Github source directly instead of Azure devops repo:

[image]

Hope this helps.